# fix modal from bootstrap ( delete only the first row ) problem

Tags: arrays, angular, bootstrap-modal

This is my modal :

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let avenant of Avenants | orderBy: 'id' ">
        <td>{{avenant.categorie?.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{avenant.numeroPolice}}</td>
        <td>{{avenant.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{avenant.dateDebut|date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteAvenant"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteAvenant" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="deleteAvenant(avenant.id)">Supprimer</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

the problem is that it always deletes the first row,
but when i remove the modal , and try using only the button it works !

This is deleteAvenant() in ts :

```js
    deleteAvenant(id:number){
      this.policeService.deleteAvenant(id).subscribe(
        data =>  {
          console.log(id);
        },
        error=> console.log(error));
        }
```

Comment: If the id being passed to the API is correct, then the problem is in the API.

Comment: no the id passed is wrong @Manish

Comment: Also, there seems to be an issue with your HTML. I see the modal is inside a `<tr>` and not `<td>`.

Comment: i added id inside <td> but the same problem @Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your modal is going to remain same, may be you should simply take it out of that loop (and table).

Now, we need to somehow let the modal know which item is supposed to be deleted.

For that, set a variable in the TS where we can hold the record's id to be deleted and set it on button's click.

**TS**

```
deleteAvenantId = 0;
```

**HTML**

```
 <button (click)="deleteAvenantId = avenant.id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"  data-toggle="modal" 
                   data-target="#deleteAvenant"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

And then then the modal changes to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"  (click)="deleteAvenant(deleteAvenantId)">Supprimer</button>
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.